# How to define structured data types in Grammar-Kit?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin, grammar-kit

I want to define a Domain Specific Language (DSL) that is structures / cascaded like this

```
ROOT
  NAME "my dsl"
  TODO
    DESC "foo"
  END
  TODO
    DESC "bar"
  END
END
```

For my understanding it needs the following rules:

- ROOT and TODO objects has to start with their keyword and end with an END.
- ROOT must have a NAME attribute.
- TODO must have a DESC attribute
- TODO is 0..n times in ROOT

How can I express such ruleset in a BNF?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Custom Language Support Tutorial](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support_tutorial.html) (Simple Language), the following BNF snippet works for me.

```
{
  tokens=[
    space='regexp:[\s\n]+'
    string="regexp:'.*'"
  ]
}

simpleFile ::= 'ROOT' space nameAttr space (todoObj space)+ 'END'
nameAttr ::= 'NAME' space string

todoObj ::= 'TODO' space descAttr space 'END'
descAttr ::= 'DESC' space string
```